# Questions on increasing RAID 5 array

Tags: hp-proliant, raid5

I'm kind of new to RAID and before I go about increasing the size of ours I would like to get some feedback on if I'm going about this the correct way. I have included as much information as I can gather about our setup, and what we would like to achieve.

HP Proliant DL380 G5
Win Server 2003 R2 Standard x64 Edition 
Processor: Intel Xeon 2.66gHz
Memory: 8.00GB RAM

Here is a physical photo of our RAID:

[image]

Here is more detailed information from the Array Configuration Utility:

[image]

I have read on the HP Smart Array Controllers User Guide. (Can't post a third link) on page 80 that: "If you insert a hot-pluggable drive into a drive bay while the system power is on, all disk activity in the array pauses for 1 or 2 seconds while the new drive is initializing. When the drive is ready, data recovery to the replacement drive begins automatically if the array is in a fault-tolerant configuration."

My big question here is, how do I find out if the array is fault tolerant? I wasn't with my company when this was set up, and I can't find it in the configuration anywhere? Is the way it's set up indicate that it has fault tolerance?

I plan on hooking up an external hard drive to the HP Proliant, and backing up the entire array using a program like clonezilla or macrium reflect before I touch anything. As well as I find out the array is fault tolerant, I would like to just replace one drive at a time while the system is on (off business hours) until the entire array is rebuilt with 1tb drives. I then believe I can use a partition manager (or maybe the Array Configuration Utility) to increase the overall size of the array to use the newly added space on the new drives.

I was thinking of purchasing 5 of these to rebuild the array on port 2 (shows up as our Data Drive on the server with 537gb) with: HP 1TB 6G SATA 7.2K rpm SFF (2.5-inch) SC Midline (can't post a 3rd link) Under the Related Products page it says these are compatible with our HP Proliant. Or would I have to get 7 of these to rebuild the entire Array A to utilize the new space?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To tell for sure, you have to view the configuration of the *logical drive* - this is where the RAID level is defined. But in your configuration, it would be untypical to not have a fault-tolerant configuration. Especially the spare drive is only of any use if you have FT logical drives defined.

As for your resizing enterprise, you would need to sequentially replace all active drives and let the rebuild happen, the result will be resized logical drive after the rebuild of the last disk has completed.

Note that the spare will kick in after you pull the first drive, so you would have to pull (or unconfigure) the spare first.

See the section "Upgrading drive capacity" in the [***user guide***](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01608507/c01608507.pdf) for a reference.

Comment: Is this what were looking for? Or how it's configured in the Array Utility? (very confusing interface, lol)   http://s21.postimg.org/9utjic1on/Drive_Managment.jpg

Comment: @ChrisDobrzeniecki first, you might want to download a more recent version of the ACU - the current/most recent version is 9.40 and it appears the interface has changed. Other than that, you should *not* be looking at the Windows disk management but the ACU "logical view". Just click the "Show logical view" link in the upper right of the configuration view window (the one you've captured and posted with your first picture in the question).

Comment: I have updated the Array Configuration Utility, and got an updated view of the logical drive. http://s21.postimg.org/gd2jf4yk7/Logical_Drive_Updated.jpg I am also now looking in to 7 of these drives: HP ProLiant DL380 G5 300GB 10K SAS 2.5" I believe doubling our size would be our best option right now. Reason being, the server is kind of old. And this will buy us 2-4 years until we upgrade the entire server. –

Comment: @ChrisDobrzeniecki if I am not mistaken, the machine you have there is a HP DL380 G5 - a server line which had reached the end-of-manufacture state by the end of 2009. So your server already *is* at least 4 years old. It likely would not last you another 4 years, you probably also would have difficulties to find workloads fitting the X5400 series CPU by that time.

Comment: This server isn't needed to be a powerhouse. It really only does backups, and shares out our network drives in the office. Even if the server breaks down next year, we can still move the new raid drives to a new server. I also looked up common parts for this server (power supply, memory, etc) and all are fairly cheap to replace if they go out. I just think it's unnecessary to upgrade an entire server that's only issue is space.